# PowerShell 4 passes the executable file path as the first parameter

Tags: c#, powershell, manifest

I am trying to run a C# console application. When I launch it in windows 8.1 using PowerShell, the file path of the executable is being passed as the first parameter. I have played around with the application and have found that something in the manifest file is causing this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly
   xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
   manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
     <requestedPrivileges>
        <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true" />
      </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

If I change the requested privileges to

```
  <requestedExecutionLevel level="asinvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

PowerShell no longer passes the file path as the first parameter. Any ideas why this happens or how to stop it? I need to leave the manifest file the way it is.

Comment: what happens if you change you line to read this instead
`<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />` this  will let the app run as administrator and OS will prompt you to grant the access right

Comment: When I set uiAccess to false, powerShell still passes the file path  as the first parameter. Only when I change both fields does powerShell pass the parameters correctly.

Comment: humm that's rather odd I was reading documentation on what could have caused your issue that is why I posted the suggestion..

Comment: Does it just happen when you launch from powershell? WHat about when you launch from command shell or explorer?

Comment: It only happens in PowerShell. I was able to find a work around, delete the manifest file, tell my application to always run as a administrator, and run PowerShell as an administrator. It lets my application run but I am still curious what is causing the issue.